# Average, Standard Deviation, and mode from text file with integers

Tags: java

I need help on my program which takes calculates the average, standard      deviation, and mode from a number of integers less than or equal to 1,000 in a text file. My program compiles, however, I end up with "null" as my output for both standard deviation and average, and "-1" for my mode.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException; 
 public class Statistics
 {
  /**default constructor for Statistics class*/
  private static int [] unmodifiedNumbers, numbers;

   public Statistics()
  {
     unmodifiedNumbers = new int [1000];
  }

    /**reads numbers from files and puts them into an array*/
    public void readFromFile()
  {

      try
      {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
        int x;
        for(x = 0; in.hasNextInt(); x++)
            unmodifiedNumbers[x] = in.nextInt();
        numbers = new int [x];
        for(int y = 0; y < x; y++)
            numbers[y] = unmodifiedNumbers[y];
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
    }

    /**calculates and returns and prints average*/
    public static double avg()
    {
      double average = 0;
     try
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
        double total = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++)  
            total += x;
        average = (double)total/numbers.length;
        System.out.println(average);

      }
      catch(Exception c)
      {
          System.out.println(c.getMessage());
      }
      return average;
    }

    /**calculates and displays mode*/
     public static void mode()
   { 

     int count = 0, mode = -1, maxCount = 0;
    try 
    {
       count = 0;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
      for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++)
       {

        for(int y = 0; y < numbers.length; y++)
            if(numbers[y] == numbers[x])
                count++;
        if(count > maxCount)
        {
            mode = numbers[x];
            maxCount = count;
        }
     }
      }
      catch(Exception b)
    {
        System.out.println(b.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(mode);
  }

  /**calculates and displays standard deviation*/
   public static void stddev()
  {
  double stddev = 0;
  long total = 0;
  double average = avg();

    try
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
      for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++)
        total += Math.pow((average - numbers[x]), 2);
      System.out.println(Math.sqrt((double)total/(numbers.length - 1)));
    }
   catch(Exception d)
   {
       System.out.println(d.getMessage());
   }
  System.out.println(stddev);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your code to test it, and make it work:

First I add a `main` to test:

```
   public static void main(String args[]){
       readFromFile();
       avg();
       mode();
       stddev();
   }
```

You can see that I call to `readFromFile`.

Because of that, I change `readFromFile` to be static.

```
/**reads numbers from files and puts them into an array*/
public static void readFromFile()
```

And I change this:

```
  /**default constructor for Statistics class*/
  private static int [] unmodifiedNumbers = new int [1000], numbers;
```

To initialize unmodifiedNumbers

Now it works.